# How to display select options based on value in Angular

Tags: html, angular, select, html-select

I want to display some options in a select list based on data in an object. For example if the data property is 0 i want to display a select option as 0 , with option to change to 1, vice versa. However in the html, no option value is played in the field. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <label for="isVisible" class="label">Set Visibility</label>
            <select *ngIf="category.isVisible === 0" class="form-select" id="isVisible" formControlName="isVisible">
                <option selected value="0">Hidden</option>
                <option value="1">Visible</option>
            </select>
            <select *ngIf="category.isVisible === 1" class="form-select" id="isVisible" formControlName="isVisible">
                <option selected value="1">Visible</option>
                <option value="0">Hidden</option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

Here is an example of an object i am passing to the html/view:

```
{
    "id": 10023,
    "product": "nike tiempo trainers",
    "price": 55.00,
    "isVisible": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not suggest doing your approach *manually*, but would suggest that just provide the `category.isVisible` value to FormControl. The reactive form will handle it.

```
<select class="form-select" id="isVisible" formControlName="isVisible">
  <option value="0">Hidden</option>
  <option value="1">Visible</option>
</select>
```

**Solution 1: Patch value to FormControl.**

*Note: This approach is not suggested if the `category` object is got from API.*

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
  isVisible: [this.category.isVisible],
});
```

**Solution 2: Patch value to FormControl.**

```js
this.form.controls.isVisible.patchValue(this.category.isVisible);
```

**Solution 3: Patch `category` object to FormGroup.**

*Note: Do consider this approach when you want to bind the whole object to the form group instead of binding each property to form control one by one.*

```js
this.form.patchValue(this.category);
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j5rkuf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)